# Get Environment Variable from Docker Container

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

What's the simplest way to get an environment variable from a docker container *that has not been declared in the Dockerfile*?

For instance, an environment variable that has been set through some `docker exec container /bin/bash` session?

I can do `docker exec container env | grep ENV_VAR`, but I would prefer something that just returns the value.

I've tried using `docker exec container echo "$ENV_VAR"`, but the substitution seems to happen outside of the container, so I don't get the env var from the container, but rather the env var from my own computer.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why would like not to use env and grep?

Comment: I just need the value. If I understand correctly, I'd need to parse the output of the grep call, and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: I had thought variable that was set in an exec session does not affect the primary process or subsequent exec sessions?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The proper way to run `echo "$ENV_VAR"` inside the container so that the variable substitution happens in the container is:

```
docker exec <container_id> bash -c 'echo "$ENV_VAR"'
```

Comment: NOTICE that all these answers depend on some shell. I'm not able to get env variables with an executable and a scratch base image.

Comment: `docker run --rm -it CONTAINER bash -c 'echo "$MY_ENV_VAR"'`

Comment: I am getting error "Error: No such container: container". I am executing command after login through SSH.

Comment: @kunwarnitesh: You need to replace "container" with the name of the container you want to operate on.

Comment: why does `docker exec <container_id> echo $ENV_VAR` not work and we have to call `bash`?

Comment: See below an alternative with printenv which I would recommend since it does not depend on a shell and does not depend on quoting to keep the variable name intact.

Answer (score 275):

To view all env variables:

```
docker exec container env
```

To get one:

```
docker exec container env | grep VARIABLE | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: My question says that I'd prefer not to go that route. Also, follow-up question: `docker exec container env` and `docker exec -it container /bin/bash` and then `env` spit out different things. Why?

Comment: Ah... might be the specific way I'm building the docker image that makes this the case...

Comment: Hm, a lot harder now. Try `docker inspect container`.

Comment: `docker inspect container` seems to have the same limitation. If I create an environment variable after I run the container, it doesn't appear in a call to `docker inspect` (in the env section).

Comment: I believe this is better answer than the currently accepted answer. We have several containers that are not supported with `bash` command, for example `alpine-node`. So using `exec container bash -c "echo $ENV_VAR"` aren't working. Using `exec container env` works for my case. Using `exec container printenv` also works.

Comment: Say @aisbaa if `VARIABLE` is a password generated from `openssl rand -base64 14` or any other case scenario where `VARIABLE` contains an equals sign then `cut -d'=' -f2` would leave out everything after the 2nd match, however, `cut -d '=' -f 2-` would only match the first delimiter and print everything after that.

Answer (score 119):

You can use `printenv VARIABLE` instead of `/bin/bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE`. It's much simpler and it does not perform substitution:

```
docker exec container printenv VARIABLE
```

Comment: This should be the final answer

Comment: or just `printenv` to print all variables.

Comment: This works even for kubernetes: kubectl exec pod-name printenv MY_VARIABLE.

Comment: container here is the container name or id

Answer (score 100):

The downside of using `docker exec` is that it requires a **running** container, so `docker inspect -f` might be handy if you're unsure a container is running.

**Example #1.** Output a list of space-separated environment variables in the specified container:

```
docker inspect -f \
   '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}{{$value}} {{end}}' container_name
```

the output will look like this:

```
ENV_VAR1=value1 ENV_VAR2=value2 ENV_VAR3=value3
```

**Example #2.** Output each env var on new line and `grep` the needed items, for example, the mysql container's settings could be retrieved like this:

```
docker inspect -f \
    '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}{{println $value}}{{end}}' \
    container_name | grep MYSQL_
```

will output:

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret
MYSQL_USER=demo
MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
MYSQL_MAJOR=5.5
MYSQL_VERSION=5.5.52
```

**Example #3.** Let's modify the example above to get a *bash friendly* output which can be directly used in your scripts:

```
docker inspect -f \
   '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}export {{$value}}{{println}}{{end}}' \
   container_name | grep MYSQL
```

will output:

```
export MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret
export MYSQL_USER=demo
export MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
export MYSQL_MAJOR=5.5
export MYSQL_VERSION=5.5.52
```

If you want to dive deeper, then go to Go’s [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package documentation with all the details of the format.

Comment: that's the best answer.
I think is should be the answer on a separate question (when container is down)

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. `docker exec` always said my container is not know.

Comment: This is the best answer because every other solution uses `docker exec` which depends on having whatever command you `exec` to be supported by the container. This answer on the other hand works for any container since it only relies on the container metadata.

Comment: could you explain why `$index`? I read https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ but still don't understand why using two variables when only one is used.

Comment: @Stefan, you're right, the `$index` is unused in the code example and we could omit it.  To be honest, I simply overlooked it at the time of writing, but now I'd leave it for a better overview of the syntax. As an example where we could still use the `$index` variable (naming it as `$key`) would be something like this `{{range $key, $value := .State}}`.

Comment: thx for the reply but I don't get your example, sorry :(. $key is not used.

Comment: @Stefan, full example will look like this: `{{range $key, $value := .State}}{{$key}}="{{$value}}"{{println}}{{end}}`.

Answer (score 20):

Since we are dealing with JSON and unlike the accepted answer, we don't need to exec the container.

```
docker inspect <NAME|ID> | jq '.[] | .Config.Env'
```

Output sample

```
[
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4",
  "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
  "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
]
```

To retrieve a specific variable

```
docker inspect <NAME|ID> | jq -r '.[].Config.Env[]|select(match("^<VAR_NAME>"))|.[index("=")+1:]'
```

See [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: This is good but it doesn't solve the problem of getting a _specific_ environment variable.

Comment: I used this `jq` to extract a specific environment variable: `docker inspect <CONTAINER> | jq -r '.[].Config.Env[]|select(match("^<VAR>"))|.[index("=")+1:]'`

Answer (score 11):

None of the above answers show you how to extract a variable from a non-running container (if you use the `echo` approach with `run`, you won't get any output).

Simply `run` with `printenv`, like so:

```
docker run --rm <container> printenv <MY_VAR>
```

(Note that `docker-compose` instead of `docker` works too)

Comment: very straightforward! I settled for this approach.

Comment: or just `printenv` to print all variables.

Answer (score 5):

If by any chance you use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and has installed the [docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker), just <kbd>right</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the docker you want to check (within the [docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker)), <kbd>click</kbd> on **Inspect**, and there search for **env**, you will find all your *env variables* values

Answer (score 1):

We can modify `entrypoint` of a non-running container with the `docker run` command.

**Example show PATH environment variable:**

1. using `bash` and `echo`: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600536/1691723) claims that `echo` will not produce any output, which is incorrect.

   ```
   docker run --rm --entrypoint bash <container> -c 'echo "$PATH"'
   ```
2. using `printenv`

   ```
   docker run --rm --entrypoint printenv <container> PATH
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@aisbaa's answer works if you don't care when the environment variable was declared. If you want the environment variable, even if it has been declared inside of an `exec /bin/bash` session, use something like:

```
IFS="=" read -a out <<< $(docker exec container /bin/bash -c "env | grep ENV_VAR" 2>&1)
```

It's not very pretty, but it gets the job done.

To then get the value, use:

```
echo ${out[1]}
```

Comment: See jwodder's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This command inspects docker stack processes' environment in the host :

```sh
pidof   dockerd containerd containerd-shim | tr ' ' '\n' \
      | xargs -L1 -I{} -- sudo xargs -a '/proc/{}/environ' -L1 -0
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way we use to find the ENV variables is `docker inspect <container name>`

The second way is `docker exec <4 alphanumeric letter of CONTAINER id> bash -c 'echo "$ENV_VAR"'`

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception in the question, that causes confusion:

**you cannot access a "running session"**, so no bash session can change anything.

```bash
docker exec -ti container /bin/bash
```

starts a new console process in the container, so if you do `export VAR=VALUE` this will go away as soon as you leave the shell, and it won't exist anymore.

Perhaps a good example:

```bash
# assuming TESTVAR did not existed previously this is empty 
docker exec container env | grep TESTVAR

# -> TESTVAR=a new value!
docker exec container /bin/bash -c 'TESTVAR="a new value!" env' | grep TESTVAR

# again empty
docker exec container env | grep TESTVAR
```

The variables from `env` come from the Dockerfile or command, docker itself and whatever the entrypoint sets.

The other answers here are good. But if you *really* need to get the environmental properties used when starting a program, then you can inspect the `/proc/pid/environ` contents in the container, where `pid` is the container process id of the running comand.

```bash
# environmental props 
docker exec container cat /proc/pid/environ | tr '\0' '\n'

# you can check this is the correct pid by checking the ran command
docker exec container cat /proc/pid/cmdline | tr '\0' ' '
```