# Docker-compose env file not working

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose, external

I'm writing as `docker-compose` file to up MySQL instance and want to use few variable from env file: here are the files actually look like:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./imran.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
    ports:
      - ${PORT1}: ${PORT2}
```

imran.env

```
PASS=imran123
PORT1=3306
PORT2=3306
```

Instead of working correct i'm getting following errors:

```
WARNING: The PASS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PORT2 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports contains unsupported option: '${PORT1}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 93):

The .env file in the project root, and the env_file: field in the Compose file are two different concepts.

The .env is for settings a default environment for Compose. Values set in this file can be used within the Compose file.

The env_file: field is for setting the default environment for a container. Values set in this can be used in the container, but not in the Compose file.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ for more information.

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted answer. To add to that then I assume `docker-compose --env-file` option is actually for setting the default environment for Compose

Comment: this answer right here folks

Comment: My goodness, thank you! The official Docker docs lists both options when talking about "Environment variables precedence" as if they were fulfilling the same purpose, just their precedence was different. But they are not interchangeable in the slightest! https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/

Comment: This is absolutely what is needed to clear the confusion and why env doesn't work as expected by someone. I was passing `--env-file` as command line option and container didn't have any of those env variables defined because `--env-file` when passed as command line option to docker compose is not for the container! Put `env_file` inside docker-compose.yml and pass the `.env` file to it and your container will have access to all the environment variables!

Comment: The best comment so far.

Answer (score 76):

You have some issues in your `docker-compose.yaml` file:

**A:**

A `space` symbol between ports values. It should be without a space:

```
ports:
  - ${PORT1}:${PORT2}
```

**B:**

You need to use [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) file in folder where `docker-compose.yaml` is in order to declaring default environment variables for both `docker-compose.yaml` file and docker container. `env_file` section is used to put values into container only.

So, you should do the following:

**1.**

Re-name file with ENV variables to `.env`:

```
mv imran.env .env
```

**2.**

Use the following `docker-compose.yaml` after:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
    ports:
      - ${PORT1}:${PORT2}
```

Comment: @imranahmedani maybe the courtesy of accepting the answer?

Comment: What about the real answer about env_file option, where I can specify the external file path, it is not working?

Comment: Downvoting. Not the right answer. The question is about how to specify an environment file explicitly.

Comment: > "env_file section is used to put values into container only" / 
That's really a fail. They should have created an option to specify custom name (and dir) for `.env` file...

Answer (score 38):

It seems that `env_file` is ignored when you add `environment` after it. In my experience, docker-compose seems to have numerous "silly" bugs like this.

Your `docker-compose.yaml` has a few errors which are irrelevant to env files. I corrected them a bit.

```
$ tre
.
├── broken
│   ├── imran.env
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
└── works
    ├── docker-compose.yaml
    └── imran.env

$ bat broken/*
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: broken/docker-compose.yaml
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ version: '3.3'
   2   │ services:
   3   │   db:
   4   │     image: mysql
   5   │     restart: always
   6   │     env_file:
   7   │       - ./imran.env
   8   │     environment:
   9   │       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
───────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: broken/imran.env
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ PASS=imran123
   2   │ MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
   3   │ PORT1=3306
   4   │ PORT2=3306
───────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────

$ diff broken works
diff broken/docker-compose.yaml works/docker-compose.yaml
8,9d7
<     environment:
<       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
```

With `environment`, it fails:

```
$ cd broken && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The PASS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Stopping broken_db_1 ... done
Removing broken_db_1 ... done
Removing network broken_default
WARNING: The PASS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "broken_default" with the default driver
Creating broken_db_1 ... done
```

But without `environment`, it works:

```
$ cd works && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
Removing works_db_1 ... done
Removing network works_default
Creating network "works_default" with the default driver
Creating works_db_1 ... done

$ docker exec -i -t works_db_1 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=ac76b84ca072
TERM=xterm
PASS=imran123
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
PORT1=3306
PORT2=3306
GOSU_VERSION=1.12
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.21-1debian10
HOME=/root
```

Notes:

- Docker-compose apparently doesn't like `${PORT1}` in `ports:`, you have to give the actual number. (in this case I just deleted it because ports are irrelevant for env files)
- The MySQL image crashes if you don't provide a root pass. I added one so the container could run long enough for me to dump its env and confirm that the variables are being set.
- I am using Docker version `19.03.5` on macOS Catalina `10.15.4`.

Comment: It seems from https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file.  When you set the same environment variable in multiple files, here’s the priority used by Compose to choose which value to use:

Compose file,
Shell environment variables,
Environment file,
Dockerfile,
Variable is not defined

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @zhfkt is right: is not a bug, configuration' `environment` key does the override of `.env` file, it's stated int the official doc.

Comment: @funder7 I don't think so. The docs state what takes precedence "when you set the same environment variable" - which is not the case here.

Comment: @Eike it states "When you run the container, the environment variable defined in the Compose file takes precedence." And also "Values in the shell take precedence over those specified in the .env file." It's explained in [this paragraph](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run)

Comment: @funder7 But which is the variable in the Compose file that would take precedence over the respective variable in the env file? All variables seem to be different?

Comment: I think something different is happening. The env_file line is feeding the docker container (docs: "You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers[sic]"). 
But the PASS variable would be needed in docker-compose already, as it's mentioned there. 
Interestingly, and in opposite to what the docs ("just like with docker run --env-file=FILE ") are saying, "docker-compose --env-file=imran.env up" works for me.

Comment: @Eike the `.env` file is applied to the whole docker project, while in the `docker-compose.yml` you define services (aka containers), each one having it's `environment` property, where you can define which environment variables to set up. Another option is to set the `env-file` property in the container definition, and every variable in the file, will be injected in the container. I hope that now it's a little more clear!

Answer (score 10):

I recently had to specify that I wanted my container to use **.env** for its environment file like:

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: myapp01xj1
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was running `docker-compose up` from a sub directory inside the project(by mistake).
So, make sure that the `docker-compose.yml` file and `.env` in the same directory, and that you are running `docker-compose up` in the same directory where both of the files exists.

Comment: does it even complain that it can't find the file or there's just some message posted but nothing breaks to disrupt stuff in some obvious way?

Comment: @jxramos As far as I remember, it was same error message as the question here is showing, but it's easy to reproduce and make sure.

Comment: This was what I needed! Days of debugging for such a simple issue...

Answer (score 7):

@nickgryg answer is good but here I will explain what I had faced when working with env. It will help others to understand.

I was also not able to access **`.my-project.env`** some variables inside docker-compose file.

**.my-project.env**

```
ROCKETTYPE=SIMPLE
RANGE=15
```

---

docker-compose.yml

```
   env_file:
      - .my-project.env
    environment:
      - SPACEX:${ROCKETTYPE}
   # It was importing RANGE env not SPACEX inside my container.
```

When I ran **`docker-compose up -d`**, only **`RANGE`** env accessible in my container.

---

**Then I came up with two solutions :**

**1st :**
Instead of using **`.my-project.env`** file only use **`.env`** file name in docker-compose.

2nd :
I did not change my env file name. Only passing **`.my-project.env`** in docker-compose command.

```
docker-compose --env-file .my-project.env  up -d
```

---

**Docker-Compose version** : `docker-compose version 1.25.0`

[Read official docker documentations](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) docker manual, if environment variables are used in `docker-compose.yml` file like:

```yaml
web:
  image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

or

```yaml
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
```

Docker looks for those variables in a default `.env` file;
So changing the default `env` file like `docker-compose up --env-file imran.env` would work.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the question have been there for a while, but for a curios posterity (like myself) the correct answer (as yours truly considers the one to be, at least) would be as follows:

1. As other good people mentioned in this discussion, `env_file` property of `docker-compose.yml` is setting environment variables for containers, not for docker-compose file, and is similar to `docker run --env-file`;
2. **By default**, environment variables in docker compose file is set by `.env` file in the same folder;
3. **To change this default file**, start your services with `docker compose --env-file` specifying an alternative `.env` file.

The answer comes directly from [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9443).

Also, please note that, as [mentioned here](https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/16113), passing an alternative dotenv file overwrites the default `.env`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `docker compose up`
Does not work on legacy `docker-compose up`

Comment: I agree with the above. In my case it only works if <docker compose up> is used and not <docker-compose up>.
    environment:
      - PORT=9999
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:80"

Comment: "Unlike Compose V1, Compose V2 integrates into the Docker CLI platform and the recommended command-line syntax is docker compose." - https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem but a bit different.

the mysql container failed to boot up because the .env beside the docker-compose.yml was not being picked up by docker-compose.

this probably happened because i had another file beside them called .env.example which confused docker-compose.

i resolved this by moving the .env.example file to another folder, but i also tried explicitly specifying the .env file in the docker-compose.yml which also worked.

i.e:

```
    env_file:
      - .env
```

i did not have a need for an environment key in my docker-compose.yml, which makes my answer less relevant to this question but i think its close enough to help others that find this question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was enough to add the parameter...

```
    env_file:
      - ./.env-MY
```

... in `docker-compose.yml` for the desired service.

**PLUS:**

The name of the `.env` file (`.env-MY`, my case) is of no importance, it can be any name.

The `--env-file ./.env-MY` parameter will not be needed for the `docker-compose` command.

It is **NOT** necessary to declare environment variables inside `docker-compose.yml`, as per this example...

```
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR_A:${ENV_VAR_A}
      - ENV_VAR_B:${ENV_VAR_B}
      - ENV_VAR_C:${ENV_VAR_C}
      - ENV_VAR_D:${ENV_VAR_D}
      - ENV_VAR_E:${ENV_VAR_E}
      - ENV_VAR_F:${ENV_VAR_F}
      - ENV_VAR_G:${ENV_VAR_G}
      - ENV_VAR_H:${ENV_VAR_H}
```

This is the example content of my `.env-MY`...

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV_VAR_A="env_var_a_val"
ENV_VAR_B="env_var_b_val"
ENV_VAR_C="env_var_c_val"
ENV_VAR_D="env_var_d_val"
ENV_VAR_E="env_var_e_val"
ENV_VAR_F="env_var_f_val"
ENV_VAR_G="env_var_g_val"
ENV_VAR_H="env_var_h_val"
```

To test whether the environment variables were loaded run the command...

```
docker-compose exec <SERVICE> env
```

... in the desired service.

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051804/3223785 ]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. I had my environment variables in a .env and was using the following in the docker -compose.yml file.

```
environment:
  - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY:${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
  - ALLOWED_HOSTS:${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
```

Changed it to

```
environment:
  - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
  - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
```

And it worked. Notice the symbol : replaced with =
Using version 3.8

Comment: you mixed two different syntax: 
- **Map syntax**:

```yml
environment:
  RACK_ENV: development
  SHOW: "true"
  USER_INPUT:
```

- **Array syntax**:

```yml
environment:
  - RACK_ENV=development
  - SHOW=true
  - USER_INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues with this today and I found the solution to it.

In the .env file, you define the variables that you need:

```
TEST='I have single quotes because I have special character$'
```

In the compose file, you must define the same variable but unset. Also, without using the equal sign:

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
    - TEST
```

Inside the container, you'll be able to run echo over your variable and see that it has been set to what you defined in the .env file.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?