# Docker add environment variables to a crashed container

Tags: docker, containers

Is it possible to add environment variables to a crashed container?

I tried

```
$ docker start --env MYVAR='value' <container_id>
$ docker exec --env MYVAR='value' <container_id> entrypoint.sh
```

But it didn't work

Comment: the question seems to be a bit abstract, but would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051747/get-environment-variable-from-docker-container/34052766 help you find some soultion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change environment variables on a container (or any other process) after it's been created.

I wouldn't bother trying to recover a container that's exited.  `docker rm` it and `docker run` a new one.  When you do `docker run` the new container, you can add or change environment variables as needed.

Answer (score 0):

[docker start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) doesn't have an `--env` option, it only starts a stopped container.

[docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) does allow setting environment variables when running a command on your container using the `--env` option.

Note that environment variables are also set when calling [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) to create the container with the `--env` option.